# Is a Salvaging shortcut available?

Tags: diablo-iii

I expect that using right-mouse button in Salvaging tab perform the action, but instead it equips the item I press. Am I missing something? Do exists a faster way to salvaging magical items to blacksmith without drag & drop them one by one?

Comment: I suspect this is intentional to avoid rage from people thinking the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On salvage tab you **left click on anvil** and then left click items you wan't to salvage.

Note:Salvaging with *Alt+Click* was availible with nephilim cube,it doesn't seem to work now but it might as well be added back.

Comment: added possible shortcut.

Comment: The shortcut mentioned doesn't work to me, but the left click on anvil I have missed. Good one, thank you.